# Inverse of Matrix

Tags: c++, arrays

Untill Now I have develped a code that can print the matrix user entered.

and try to calculate mathematically the inverse but i couldn't receive proper results .
it get the deteminant by a function and then get step by step every new element of the new matrix  that is inverse for the old one

i tried to do it simply 
this is my code 
i want a better algorithm for doing this mission

```
      #include <iostream>
     #include <stdlib.h>

       using namespace std;

     float Det (int  arr [3][3] )
      {

int res = arr[0][0]*(arr[1][1]*arr[2][2]-arr[2][1]*arr[1][2])-arr[0][1]*(arr[1][0]*arr[2][2]-arr[1][2]*arr[2][0])+arr[0][2]*(arr[1][0]*arr[2][1]-arr[1][1]*arr[2][0]);

return res ;

    }

  int main()
  {
int arr [3][3] ={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}};
float inv [3][3]={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}};
for(unsigned i = 0 ; i<3 ;i++)
{
    for(unsigned j= 0 ;j<3 ;j++)
    {
        cout << "Enter The Value Of The Element < " <<i+1<<" , "<<j+1<<" > :" ;
        cin >> arr [i][j] ;
    }
}
system("cls") ;
float det = Det(arr) ;

for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ;i++)
{
    for(unsigned j = 0 ; j< 3 ; j++)
    {
        unsigned m [2]={i+1,i+2} ;
        unsigned n [2]={j+1,j+2} ;
        for(unsigned k = 0 ; k< 2 ;k++)
        {
            if(m[k]>2)
            {
                m[k]=0;
                swap(m[0],m[1]);

            }
            if(n[k]>2)
            {
                n[k]=0;
                swap(n[0],n[1]) ;

            }

        }
        inv [i][j] = arr[m[0]][n[0]]*arr[m[1]][n[1]]-arr[m[0]][n[1]]*arr[m[1]][n[0]] ;
        if((i+j)%2!=0)
        {
            inv [i] [j] = -inv[i][j] ;
        }
        inv [i] [j] = (1/det) * inv[i] [j];
    }
}
swap(inv[0][1],inv[1][0]);
swap(inv[2][1],inv[1][2]);
swap(inv[0][2],inv[2][0]);


cout << " Your Matrix is "<<endl ;
for(unsigned i = 0 ; i<3 ;i++)
{
    cout<< "     " ;
    for(unsigned j= 0 ;j<3 ;j++)
    {

        cout<< arr [i][j]<< "  " ;
    }
    cout <<endl<<endl ;
}


cout<< "DET =  "<<det <<endl ;


cout << " Your Inverse is "<<endl ;
for(unsigned i = 0 ; i<3 ;i++)
{
    cout<< "     " ;
    for(unsigned j= 0 ;j<3 ;j++)
    {

        cout<< inv [i][j]<< "  " ;
    }
    cout <<endl<<endl ;
}
  }
```

Comment: Some variant of gaussian elimination or gauss-jordan elimination is often considered preferable to computing determinants of cofactors, as you are.   That said, for a 3x3, the error is most likely in your coding (i.e. not coding the algorithm correctly) rather than an intrinsic property of using determinants and cofactors.

Comment: All depends on the size of the problem and the sparsity of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

@MahmoudMohammad. Think of your code as a poem. It needs to be clear, well indented for readability reasons, and commented. As @Peter mentioned above, you use other efficient methods than the trivial gaussian elimination technique, for this can be computationally very expensive as the size of the matrix get bigger. However,  you can improve your code by reading [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adjoint-inverse-matrix/) or [this](https://programwithcode.com/codeUtility/cplusplus-program/474). See [also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition) for more on other methods

Answer (score 0):

```
struct matris
{
    static matris matris_ans;
    int en; // {0};
    int boy;// = 0;
    int top;// = 0;
    double *p;// = NULL;


    matris();
    matris(int _boy,int _en);
    matris(double *_p,int _boy,int _en);
    matris(matris &m);     
    matris( dbl a, dbl b, dbl c,
            dbl d, dbl e, dbl f,
            dbl g, dbl h, dbl i);
    matris( dbl a, dbl b, dbl c, dbl d,
            dbl e, dbl f, dbl g, dbl h,
            dbl i, dbl j, dbl k, dbl l,
            dbl m, dbl n, dbl o, dbl p);

    ~matris();

    matris& operator = (matris &m);
    matris  operator + (matris &m) ;
    matris  operator * (matris &m) ;

    double& operator () (int _boy, int _en);
    double* operator [] (int kk);

    double   al(int _boy, int _en);
    double &koy(int _boy, int _en);

    void degistir(int _boy,int _en);
    void degistir(double *_p,int _boy,int _en);
    void reset();
    void sifir();
    void birim();
    void yaz_konsola();
    void yaz_dosyaya(char *isim );
    void yaz_resme(char *isim);
    matris trn();

    friend void matris_copy(matris *m1, matris *m2);                //m2 yi m1 e kopyalar
    friend void matris_topla(matris *m1, matris *m2, matris *m3);   //m1=m2+m3
    friend void matris_carp(matris *m1, matris *m2, matris *m3);    //m1=m2*m3
    friend void matris_ident(matris *m1, int say);                  //matrisi birim matris yapar
    friend void matris_trn(matris *m1);                             //matrisi ters çevirir
    friend matris matris_trn(matris &m1);                           //
    friend void matris_inverse(matris *a, matris *m);               //matrisin inversini alır

    static void test1();


};

//MATRIS
matris  matris::matris_ans;
        matris::matris()// :en(0),boy(0),p(0),top(0)
{
    en=0;   boy=0;  p=0;    top=0;
}  
        matris::matris(int _boy,int _en)//  :en(_en),boy(_boy)
{
    en=_en; boy=_boy;   top=_en*_boy;
    p=new double[top];

    for(int i=0;i<top;i++) p[i]=0;
}  
        matris::matris(double *_p,int _boy,int _en)
{
    en=_en; boy=_boy;   top=en*boy;
    p=new double[top];
    for(int i=0;i<top;i++)  p[i]=_p[i];
}  

        matris::matris(matris &m)
{
    boy=m.boy;
    en =m.en;
    top=m.top;
    p=new double[top];
    for(int i=0;i<top;i++) p[i]=m.p[i];
}  
        matris::~matris()
{
    delete p;
}
        matris::matris( dbl a, dbl b, dbl c,
                        dbl d, dbl e, dbl f,
                        dbl g, dbl h, dbl i)
{
    en =3;  boy=3;  top=en*boy;
    p = new double[top] {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};
}
        matris::matris( dbl a, dbl b, dbl c, dbl d,
                        dbl e, dbl f, dbl g, dbl h,
                        dbl i, dbl j, dbl k, dbl l,
                        dbl m, dbl n, dbl o, dbl p)
{
    en =4;
    boy=4;
    top=en*boy;
    this->p = new double[top]
    {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p};

}  
double  matris::al(int _boy, int _en)
{
    return p[_boy*en+_en];
}
double& matris::koy(int _boy, int _en)
{
    return p[_boy*en + _en];
}
double& matris::operator () (int _boy, int _en)
{
    return p[_boy*en + _en];
}

void    matris::degistir(int _boy,int _en)
{
    if (en == _en && boy == _boy)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < top; i++)   p[i] = 0;
        return;
    }
    en=_en; boy=_boy;   top=en*boy;
    if (p) delete p;
    p=new double[top];
    for(int i=0;i<top;i++)  p[i]=0;
}
void    matris::degistir(double *_p,int _boy,int _en)
{
    if(en == _en)   // (en=_en && boy==_boy)
    if(boy == _boy)
    {
        memcpy(p, _p, top * sizeof(double));
        return;
    }


    en=_en;
    boy=_boy;
    top=en*boy;
    if (p) delete p;//[] gerek yok heralde
    p=new double[top];
    for(int i=0;i<top;i++) p[i]=_p[i];
} 
void    matris::reset()
{
    if (p) delete p;
    memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));
}
void    matris::sifir()
{
    if(p)   memset(p, 0, en*boy * sizeof(double));
}
void    matris::birim()
{
    sifir();
    for (int i = 0; i < en; i++)
        p[i + i * en] = 1;

}
void    matris::yaz_konsola()
{
    printf("matris(%4d,%4d)=\n",boy,en);

    for(int j=0;j<boy;j++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<en ;i++)
            printf("%9.2g ",p[j*en+i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void    matris::yaz_dosyaya(char *_dosya_ismi)
{
    FILE *yaz;
    yaz = fopen(_dosya_ismi, "w");
    fprintf(yaz,"matris(%4d,%4d)\n",boy,en);

    for(int j=0;j<boy;j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < en; i++)
            if (p[j*en + i])
                    fprintf(yaz, "a");//    fprintf(yaz, "%12.4g ", p[j*en + i]);
            else    fprintf(yaz, " ");
        fprintf(yaz,"\n");
    }


    fprintf(yaz,"\n");
    fclose(yaz);

}
void    matris::yaz_resme(char *_dosya_ismi)
{
    resim r(boy, en);

    resim::renk byz = { 255,255,255,255 },
                gri = { 128,128,128,128 };

    for (int j = 0; j < boy; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < en; i++)
            if (p[j*en + i])
                    r[j][i] = byz;
            else    r[j][i] = gri;
    }


    r.kaydet(_dosya_ismi);

}
matris& matris::operator = (matris &m)
{
    degistir(m.p, m.boy, m.en);
    return *this;
}
matris  matris::operator + (matris &m)
{

    matris_ans.degistir(boy,en);

    for(int i=0;i<top;i++)
        matris_ans.p[i]=p[i]+m.p[i];

    return matris_ans;
}
matris  matris::operator * (matris &m)
{
    matris_ans.degistir(boy, m.en);


    int _boy=boy;
    int _en=m.en;
    int _say=en;

    for(int i=0; i<_boy; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<_en;  j++)
    for(int k=0; k<_say; k++)
    {
        matris_ans[i][j] += (*this)[i][k] * m[k][j];
    }

    return matris_ans;//kopya döndür 
}  
double* matris::operator [] (int kk)
{
    return p + en * kk;// (&p[en*kk]);
}
matris  matris::trn()
{
    matris a(en,boy);
    for(int i=0;i<boy;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<en;j++)
        a.koy(j,i)=al(i,j);//m1 i ters çevirip a ya koy
    return a;
}  

void    matris_copy(matris *m1,matris *m2)
{
    //eski sitil
    m1->degistir(m2->boy,m2->en);
    memcpy(m1->p,  m2->p,  m2->top*sizeof(double));//m2 nin belleğini m1 e kopyala
}
void    matris_topla(matris *m1,matris *m2,matris *m3)
{
    m1->degistir(m2->boy,m2->en);
    int top=m3->top;
    for(int i=0;i<top;i++)
        m1->p[i]=m2->p[i]+m3->p[i]; 
}  
void    matris_carp(matris *m1,matris *m2,matris *m3)
{
    int say=m2->en;
    int boy=m2->boy;
    int en=m3->en;
    m1->degistir(boy,en);

    for(int i=0;  i<boy;  i++)
    for(int j=0;  j<en;   j++)
    for(int k=0;  k<say;  k++)
        m1->koy(i,j) += m2->al(i,k) * m3->al(k,j); 

}  
void    matris_ident(matris *m1,int say)
{
    if (m1->en == say && m1->boy == say)
    {
        //m1->sifir();
        if (m1->p)  memset(m1->p, 0, say*say * sizeof(double));
        for (int i = 0; i < say; i++)  m1->koy(i, i) = 1;
        return;
    }
    m1->degistir(say,say);
    for(int i=0;i<say;i++)  m1->koy(i,i)=1;

}  
void    matris_trn(matris *m1)
{
    matris *a=new matris(m1->en,m1->boy);;//en boy ters yeni a matrisi
    for(int i=0;i<m1->boy;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<m1->en;j++)
        a->koy(j,i)=m1->al(i,j);//m1 i ters çevirip a ya koy
    matris_copy(m1,a); //a yı m1 e kopyala
    delete a;

}  
matris  matris_trn(matris &m1)
{
    matris a(m1.en,m1.boy);
    for(int i=0;i<m1.boy;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<m1.en;j++)
            a.koy(j,i)=m1.al(i,j);//m1 i ters çevirip a ya koy
    return a;//kopya döndür ama silinecek

}  
void    matris_inverse(matris *a,matris *m)//m matrisinin inversini a matrisine koy
{
    int boy=m->boy;
    int en=m->en;
    matris_ident(a,boy);//a matrisini birim matris yapalım


    for(int i=0;i<en;i++)//sütunları dön
    {


        for(int j=0;j<boy;j++)//satırları dön
        {               
            int k;//dolu satırın yeri
            for(k=i;k<boy;k++)//dolu satırı bul i den itibaren
            {
                if(m->al(k,i)==0) continue;//sıfırsa atla  i hangi en sütünundayız o                        
                break;//sıfır değil demek bu bana lazım k dolu satırım
            }

            //dolu satırı köşeye koy
            double temp;
            for(int t=0;t<en;t++)//matrisin i==j satırlarını doluyla değişelim
            {
                temp=m->al(i,t);    m->koy(i,t) = m->al(k,t);   m->koy(k,t)=temp;  //m matrisi
                temp=a->al(i,t);    a->koy(i,t) = a->al(k,t);   a->koy(k,t)=temp;  //a matrisi
            }

            //dolu satırı 1 yap
            double kk=m->al(i,i);
            for(int t=0;t<en;t++)
            {
                m->koy(i,t)=m->al(i,t)/kk;  //m matrisi
                a->koy(i,t)=a->al(i,t)/kk;  //a matrisi
            }
            break;
        }


        for(int j=0;j<boy;j++)//diğer satırları 0 yap
        {
            if(m->al(j,i)==0) continue;//zaten sıfırmış gerek yok
            if(j==i) continue;         //bu satırı geç 
            double kk=m->al(j,i);
            for(int t=0;t<en;t++)
            {
                m->koy(j,t)-=m->al(i,t)*kk; //m matrisi
                a->koy(j,t)-=a->al(i,t)*kk; //a matrisi
            }
        }


    }

}
void    matris::test1()
{
    printf("<<<<<<<<<<hesap_matris()\n");

    double pp[] = { 0,0,1,9,
                    5,0,9,0,
                    2,7,0,5,
                    0,3,0,6 };
    matris mat_b(pp, 4, 4);

    mat_b.yaz_konsola();

    matris mat_c;
    matris_inverse(&mat_c, &mat_b);
    mat_b.yaz_konsola();
    mat_c.yaz_konsola();


    memcpy(mat_b.p, pp, 16 * sizeof(double));

    //1000*1000 luk matris yapıp inversini al
    matris mat_k;
    matris_ident(&mat_k, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        mat_k.p[i] = sin(double(i));

    mat_k.yaz_konsola();
    matris_inverse(&mat_c, &mat_k);
    mat_c.yaz_konsola();
    mat_k.yaz_konsola();

    /*
    matris_inverse(&mat_k, &mat_c);
    mat_k.yaz_konsola();
    matris_inverse(&mat_c, &mat_k);
    mat_c.yaz_konsola();
    */



    matris m(
        0, 0, 1, 9,
        5, 0, 9, 0,
        2, 7, 0, 5,
        0, 3, 0, 6), m3=m;
    m3 = m * m + m;
    /*
    m.yaz_konsola();
    m3.yaz_konsola();
    */





}
```